# cocoa - unarchivedObjectOfClass does not call initWithCoder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I am developing a macOS app using objective-C.

I tried to save a NSArray object in Core Data. I write

```
- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value
{
  return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[NSArray class] fromData:value error:nil];
}
```

in the class that inherits NSValueTransformer.

And one of elements in my NSArray object is not of primary kind(which has properties called courseName and courseInfos), so I conform  in this element's class. In this class ,I write:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [[self class] new];
    if (self = [super init])
    {
         self.courseName = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"courseName"];
         self.courseInfos = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"courseInfos"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

When my apps runs, the reverseTransformedValue: method is called, and all elements but that special nonprimary element in my NSArray object are decoded. I put a breakpoint in the initWithCoder: method in that special element's class, and it never runs. I use some tools and find that element is successfully stored in my core data, so its encoding process has no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed it, here is the solution:

My object is 'Address' (note: it is not NSArray)

**Address.h**

```
@interface Address : NSObject <NSSecureCoding>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *street;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *city;

@end
```

**Address.m**

```
@implementation Address
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{

    self = [self init];
    if (self == nil) 
   {
        return nil;
    }

    self.street = [aDecoder decodeObjectOfClass:[Address class] forKey:@"street"];

    self.city = [aDecoder decodeObjectOfClass:[Address class]
                                         forKey:@"city"];
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder 
{

    [encoder encodeObject:self.street forKey:@"street"];

    [encoder encodeObject:self.city forKey:@"city"];

}

+ (BOOL)supportsSecureCoding 
{

    return YES;

}
```

**Archive.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Address *address;
```

**Archive.m**

```
UserDBO *userDBO = [[UserDBO alloc] init];
```

*// Archive*

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.address requiringSecureCoding:YES error:&error];

    if(error) 
    {

        NSLog(@"archivedDataWithRootObject: %@", error);

    }

userDBO.address = data;
```

*// UnArchive*

```
Address *address = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[Address class] fromData:userDBO.address error:&error];

        if(error) 
       {

            NSLog(@"unarchivedObjectOfClass: %@", error);

        }
```

**UserDBO.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *address;
```